# access a network device through a jump server using Jumpssh

Tags: python, networking, ssh, automation, netmiko

I was trying to login into router from jump server. I tried this code but it is giving error which i am not able to understand. Please let me know how to solve this error or any other ways to login into router from jump server.

Tried code:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import jumpssh
import os
from jumpssh import SSHSession
load_dotenv()
jumpserver_ip = os.getenv("jumpserver_ip")
jumpserver_username = os.getenv("jumpserver_username")
jumpserver_password = os.getenv("jumpserver_password")
remote_ip = os.getenv("remote_ip")
remote_password = os.getenv("remote_password")
gateway_session = SSHSession(jumpserver_ip, jumpserver_username, password=jumpserver_password).open()

remote_session = gateway_session.get_remote_session(remote_ip, password=remote_password, allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False)
fl = open('R1.txt', 'w')
fl.write(remote_session.get_cmd_output('show running config'))
fl.close()
remote_session.close()
gateway_session.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python3\JUMPSE~1\jump\DOTENV~1\lib\site-packages\jumpssh\session.py", line 160, in open
    self.ssh_client.connect(**self.extra_parameters)
  File "C:\python3\JUMPSE~1\jump\DOTENV~1\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 446, in connect
    passphrase,
  File "C:\python3\JUMPSE~1\jump\DOTENV~1\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 764, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
  File "C:\python3\JUMPSE~1\jump\DOTENV~1\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 751, in _auth
    self._transport.auth_password(username, password)
  File "C:\python3\JUMPSE~1\jump\DOTENV~1\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1509, in auth_password
    return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event)
  File "C:\python3\JUMPSE~1\jump\DOTENV~1\lib\site-packages\paramiko\auth_handler.py", line 250, in wait_for_response
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jump.py", line 17, in <module>
    remote_session = gateway_session.get_remote_session(remote_ip, password=remote_password, allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False)
  File "C:\python3\JUMPSE~1\jump\DOTENV~1\lib\site-packages\jumpssh\session.py", line 514, in get_remote_session
    retry_interval=retry_interval)
  File "C:\python3\JUMPSE~1\jump\DOTENV~1\lib\site-packages\jumpssh\session.py", line 174, in open
    % (self.host, self.port, self.username), original_exception=ex)
jumpssh.exception.ConnectionError: Unable to connect to '10.10.10.1:22' with user 'abc': Authentication failed.
```

My jump.env file:

```
jumpserver_ip = 'your_jump_server_ip'
jumpserver_username = 'your_jump_server_username'
jumpserver_password = 'your_jump_server_password'
remote_ip = 'your_remote_node_ip'
remote_username = 'your_remote_node_username'
remote_password = 'your_remote_node_password'
```

Let me know whats the issue or any other way to login.

Comment: Looks like you've given `None` as the hostname. (aka: `remote_ip`)

Comment: @Torxed no there is ip i have given. May be i am not getting how to write .env file. if u know please let me kow

Comment: Out of curiosity, do `print(jumpserver_ip)` to confirm you actually get the result you expect.

Comment: @Torxed yes it is printing None for everything. Now how to save all ips? in .env file.

Comment: No clue, I usually do parameter driven or `jumpserver_ip=192.168.0.1 python myscript.py` : )